# How to get result filtering on a particular date from a table and aligning it with other table with latest timestamp from other table on a given day?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive, hiveql

I am using the below query to get the results I have shown in the below table. I am looking to modify the query to get the expected result as shown in last table. I would like to align the latest timestamp (start_time) with the manufacture_date (string).  Also, if a "manufacture_date" from Vehicles table doesn't have any result in modem_auth table then the lifecycle_mode, auth_status, start_time, end_time column should show NULL in the result. Basically I would like to show all the records from vehicles table.

```
    SELECT v.vin,
           date_Format(v.manufacture_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS event_date,
           "Vehicle Manufactured" AS event_desc,
           m.lifecycle_mode,
           m.auth_status,
           m.start_time,
           m.end_time
      FROM vehicles v
INNER JOIN (SELECT vin, MAX(created_on) AS max_created_on FROM vehicles GROUP BY vin) v2 
        ON v.vin = v2.vin AND 
           v.created_on = v2.max_created_on
 LEFT JOIN modem_auth m 
        ON v.vin = m.vin AND
           (date_Format(v.manufacture_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE(m.start_time) AND TO_DATE(m.end_time)) AND
           save.vin_2 IN ('LMN12345', 'XYZ12345', 'ABC12345')
     WHERE m.partition_region = 'NA' AND
           m.partition_country = 'USA'
```

Result I am getting -

| vin | event_date | event_desc | lifecycle_mode | auth_status | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LMN12345 | 8/2/2021 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | WAITING_FOR_AUTH | 08/02/2021 16:35:15 | 09/02/2021 13:28:29 |
| XYZ12345 | 11/12/2020 | Vehicle Manufactured | NORMAL | NOT_AUTHORIZED | 11/10/2020 05:09:44 | 11/12/2020 16:19:53 |
| XYZ12345 | 11/12/2020 | Vehicle Manufactured | NORMAL | NOT_AUTHORIZED | 11/12/2020 16:19:53 | 06/12/2021 00:00:30 |
| ABC12345 | 6/13/2019 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | UNPROVISIONED | 06/13/2019 21:20:42 | 06/13/2019 21:20:58 |
| ABC12345 | 6/13/2019 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | WAITING_FOR_HOME_URL | 06/13/2019 21:20:58 | 06/13/2019 22:10:32 |
| ABC12345 | 6/14/2019 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | WAITING_FOR_USER | 06/13/2019 22:10:32 | 11/01/2019 12:18:32 |

Expected Result -

| vin | event_date | event_desc | lifecycle_mode | auth_status | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LMN12345 | 8/2/2021 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | WAITING_FOR_AUTH | 08/02/2021 16:35:15 | 09/02/2021 13:28:29 |
| XYZ12345 | 11/12/2020 | Vehicle Manufactured | NORMAL | NOT_AUTHORIZED | 11/12/2020 16:19:53 | 06/12/2021 00:00:30 |
| ABC12345 | 6/14/2019 | Vehicle Manufactured | NULL | WAITING_FOR_USER | 06/13/2019 22:10:32 | 11/01/2019 12:18:32 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple rows coming out of table m (modem_auth) for a single vin. You need to boil the rows coming out of m down to a maximum of one per vin, which means you will need to make a table expression out of it that includes a `group by vin` clause. (I'm a little confused about the event_date column in the first table, as if vin is the primary key of vehicles you wouldn't have two different dates for the same vin as the table shows for ABC12345.)

What you need to do is create a table expression based on modem_auth that identifies the one row per vin that you want to use in the outer join to vehicles, that row being the one with the latest start_time. So replace

```
LEFT JOIN modem_auth m 
 ON v.vin = m.vin AND
       (date_Format(v.manufacture_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE(m.start_time) AND TO_DATE(m.end_time))
```

with

```
LEFT JOIN modem_auth m
   INNER JOIN (select ma2.vin, max(ma2.start_time) AS start_time from modem_auth ma2
               INNER JOIN vehicles v2 ON v2.vin = ma2.vin
                   AND date_Format(v2.manufacture_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN
                        TO_DATE(ma2.start_time) AND TO_DATE(ma2.end_time)
               group by ma2.vin) mamax ON m.vin = mamax.vin AND m.start_time = mamax.start_time
 ON v.vin = m.vin AND
       (date_Format(v.manufacture_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') BETWEEN TO_DATE(m.start_time) AND TO_DATE(m.end_time))
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin! Inner joining on modem_auth on max(start_time) would only get a record which has highest start_time timestamp for that particular VIN. But we want the timestamp from modem_auth which has a date from Vehicles table.

Comment: Can vehicles really have multiple rows for a single vin as the first inner join implies?

Comment: Vehicles table has one row per VIN. Consider it as a master table for any VIN. But Modem_Auth table will have many rows per vehicle because a modem from every vehicle will send a data at a fixed time interval.  e.g. consider it as a timeseries data being generated by a vehicle at a fixed 2 hour interval. If user is making some changes in modem authorization, then those changes will reflect in a row along with the timestamp.

Comment: I added an INNER JOIN to the new table expression that should ensure that only rows that would match the primary table row will come out of the table being outer joined to.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! It provided me a guideline to use it in my actual code to get.